# Android remove divider between context menu

Tags: android

This is my menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

>
<!--  Item 1 -->
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu1"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Item 1"/>
<!--  Item 2 -->
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu2"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Item 2">

</item>


<!--  Item 3 -->
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu3"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="Item 3"/>

<!--  Item 4 -->
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu4"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Item 4">

</item>
<!--  close Item 4 -->
```

I want to remove the divider between item I try this

```
 android:divider="@null"
```

on menu but no thing changed the result

Picture with Divider line in Context menu:

[image]

Expected Outcome :

[image]

i just want to make its style like this (facebook messenger) or this menu made with some think else not Context menu ?

Comment: I believe the second image is a dialog fragment with a ListView or LinearLayout

Comment: @AmanGrover _yes thats what i think its not_ `Context Menu`